# Sequence and progressive matrix with abstract geometric shapes

Tags: pattern, visual, sequence

[image: Picture 1]

[image: Picture 2]

I can't fathom any kind of pattern in these questions. The test is over but I'm curious to know how it should be solved.

Comment: For content that is not your own, please **[provide attribution](/help/referencing)**. Using someone else's content without (at minimum) disclosing where it came from is plagiarism, and such posts are deleted.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Given the combination of the two questions, I think the answers are:

> B and D

---

### Explanation:

If we look at the

> number of line segments in each image

we find that in the first image we have

> `2 2 4 6`

which should be continued by

> `10` to form double the Fibbonaci sequence

and in the second image we have

> ```
> 8  6  5
> 12 10 9
>    4  3
> ```

which should have, in the bottom left corner

> `6` to keep the differences in each row/column constant between different rows/columns.

Comment: Another more elegant way to express the rule is that in every subsquare of 4 numbers the diagonal sums are equal.  8+10 = 6+12, 6+9 = 5+10, ...

Answer (score 1):

I also solved it the same way and got the same answer as the previous comment (without looking at theirs I mean). To elaborate further if you are still a bit confused, for the second problem you find the number of sides of each shape which are:

```
8  6  5  
12 10 9  
   4  3
```

vertically, the difference between the first two numbers of each row is +4 and between the last two is -6. Horizontally the difference of the first two is -2 then -1. Therefore 12-6=6 or 4+2=6, so the answer has 6 sides. The only answer with six sides is number 4, the hexagon.

Answer (score 0):

Each shape appears with this sequence: 2 1
The second set begins with 12, we remove 2, the next shape starts with 10, and for the following figure, we remove 1, therefore obtaining the number 9.

Comment: I don't understand how this answer relates to the question. What do the numbers mean here?